# Does the 'Asus B150 M Plus' motherboard support a DDR4 CL16 RAM?

Tags: memory, motherboard, desktop-computer

I know that the motherboard can support RAM of any frequency and will downclock it to 2133Mhz but can it support a RAM of latency type CL16? I'm currently running a CL14 2133Mhz 8Gb HyperX stick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crucial RAM sticks for the
[Asus B150 M Plus](https://www.crucial.com/compatible-upgrade-for/asus/b150m-plus-d3)
are only recommended for **DDR3L**-1600 with CL=11.
If that's truly your model, then
you are already pushing your motherboard beyond its limits,
and it is quite possible that your CL14 RAM is not functioning at this speed.

However, if your motherboard was the
[B150M-PLUS](https://www.crucial.com/compatible-upgrade-for/asus/b150m-plus),
which seems more likely in view of your being able to clock it up to 2133Mhz,
then it could go up to **DDR4**-3600 with CL=19.

Finding out your exact motherboard model should be your first step.

Comment: It’s worth pointing out that DD3 motherboards are incompatible with DDR4.  Likewise, DDR4 motherboards are incompatible with DDR3.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

https://www.asus.com/in/Motherboards/B150M-PLUS/

This is my model. It is a DDR4 type motherboard. That said, it can support RAM of frequency upto 3600 and latency upto CL19 right? 

I am planning on purchasing a HyperX 8GB 2666Mhz DDR4 CL16 stick.

Comment: I have updated my answer with the correct Crucial page. You can indeed go up to DDR4-3600 CL=19. These two are not the only parameters to watch for, so perhaps better go with Crucial or any other manufacturer that guarantees compatibility with your motherboard.

Comment: Thank you. Don't have enough rep to upvote but did do it.